# How to disable IPN for a specific button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We're running WPMUdev's Memberships plugin, which requires that the default IPN lister URL be set in one's PayPal profile (because even though the subscribe buttons include notify_url, without a default IPN listener set, apparently there's no way to get recurring payment cancellation messages) — and that all works just fine.

Trouble is, PayPal can't tell the difference between buttons generated by this plugin and manually generated buttons (eg one-off donation), and tries to send IPN messages to the plugin's listener, which gets completely confused because the expected metadata isn't sent with it.  PayPal then retries the IPN until its limit is reached.

Is there some way to use `notify_url` (or some other HTML variable) to disable IPN messages for a specific button?  Or will I have to write a null IPN listener that simply acknowledges IPN messages and drops them on the floor?

Comment: Just a thought (been a while since I've used IPN), how about appending some query string to the URL you want to single out so _your listener_ can identify? At the end of the day, all Paypal really does is send you _messages_ (where you tell them to, account or overridden via `notify_url`).

Comment: @EdSF, Not a good idea, even if I did create the necessary local DB records to prevent the existing listener from rejecting the IPN.  Remember, the listener is there for a reason, and expects to change local state as the result of a paypal event.  Making manually-created buttons look like buttons belonging to the plugin is likely to break the plugin.  I guess I'll have to write a custom listener :(  There are enough template implementations around, I'm just annoyed I have to have this extra, pointless step.

Comment: It's the other way around, you're just identifying the "one offs" and may not even need to do any db stuff. If you have "one off buttons" that your listener _should_ "disregard", the idea is to keep your existing working implementation as is, and only "one off" the "occasional button" - e.g. with a querystring - you only identify the "one offs" (nothing more) - it could be a simple as `if has "foo" querystring just respond but don't do anything in backend`. I guess it all depends on what you mean by "one off"...

Comment: @EdSF maybe we're talking about different things.  The trouble is that the memberships plugin gets IPN requests for manually-created buttons unless I provide an explicit override with `notify_url`, but with manually created buttons, there *is* no listener unless I write one.  If it is not possible to disable IPNs for a specific button, then I need to point the manually-created buttons to a listener that will do something sensible with the notification (including correctly acknowledge the message).

Comment: Right so in your "manually created button" (_a one off/occasional need_), you'd assign a `notify_url` along the lines of `http://my-current-listener.com?disregard=me` - at which point your listener just responds properly and not do anything else. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yep.  In fact, just pointing `notify_url` at a simple text file seems to do the trick.  I was under the misapprehension that the listener had to positively acknowledge the IPN but, as @Andrew Angell said below, it's the 200 response code that counts; the call back is just to validate the POSTed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @EdSF said is what I would recommend.

Setup an IPN listener that does nothing but return a 200 OK back to PayPal.  It doesn't have to actually do anything.

Then set that URL as the value of notify_url in the button that you want to "disable".

This will way you won't end up with loops of IPNs from PayPal trying to hit a bogus URL that doesn't exist.

Comment: Guess I have to write a null listener, then.  Seems a pity I can't just tell PP not to send IPN for this button.  Returning 200 on its own will probably not, however, be enough: according to PP docs, the listener must append a string and call something or other back to get a VALID/INVALID response (so, 2 way handshake)

Comment: All that does is validate the data so that you're sure it came from PayPal.  In this case you don't care about that, so you don't need to do that.  Really, a simple IPN script that does literally nothing would suffice.  It would take 2 min to setup.

Comment: Okay, so long as PayPal doesn't care about not receiving a cmd=_notify-validate then sure, a do-nothing endpoint would work.  I guess I interpreted PayPal's docs a little more unforgivingly.  Does the IPN call from PayPal care at all about the content (or type) of the data the IPN endpoint returns, or only the HTTP result code?

Comment: It doesn't care at all about the data.  It just needs a 200 response back from the HTTP POST that PayPal sends to your URL.  As long as you have a page loading at that URL without error, it'll be fine.  It could literally be an empty page.

Answer (score -1):

In the scenario I've described, it's evident that providing a null `notify_url` doesn't work (the default IPN listener URL is still used) therefore (unless a more experienced PayPal developer can indicate otherwise), and as @Andrew Angell said, it will be necessary to provide an IPN listener that simply acknowledges the IPN message (and maybe logs it, if desired).

Note that, as described in [PayPal's documentation](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside), it is not sufficient simply to reply with an HTTP 200 response; PayPal will continue to retry IPNs until the limit is exceeded or the configured listener responds with the appropriate positive acknowledgement described in that link.

There are any number of IPN listener templates available on the web, so that is one option, however here's another that has only just occurred to me:

There are one or two IPN multiplexor scripts floating around, for example, [this one](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/multiples-ipn-dynamically-setting-the-notification-url#post-608459), though I haven't yet tried it so can't speak to its quality or suitability.  But I'd guess that using a pre-existing multiplexor script would be the sensible thing to do because a) it deals with the problem I presented in my OP, and b) it provides a ready-made mechanism for dealing with other applications that make use of IPN, should the need arise.

Comment: HTTP 200 *is* the 'positive acknowledgement'. Your link states that you *also* need to engage in the verification protocol, but that isn't a 'positive acknowledgment'.

Comment: You don't need to validate the IPN.  That is not what stops the PayPal server from sending more IPNs.  The 200 OK happens when any page is loaded successfully from your server.  That's what stops further IPNs.  A script with literally nothing in it, but that at least loads successfully when hit with a browser, would be just fine.